# Windows has inserted a halloween picture in the start menu. How do I turn it off

Tags: windows, windows-10, themes

Without me requesting it, Windows is showing Halloween-themed picture in my search box on the start menu. How do I kill this nonsense? Asking now, because if it starts showing me Thanksgiving or Christmas-themed search boxes I'm totally going to hurl it into the nearest lake.

[image: Halloween themed search bar image]

It's Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎21/‎10/‎2022
OS build    19042.2130
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0

Comment: Right click on the magnifying glass and turn off News and Interests

Comment: Halloween is celebrated around the world in many countries.  It didnt even originate in the US.

Comment: Turning off news and interests didn't work, even after a restart. @Keltari Jack-o-lanterns did originate in the US. Although Halloween is a Christian tradition that didn't originate in the US, the style of celebration this decoration references is totally US-specific

Comment: @stib off topic for SU, there is a modicum of truth to your statements.  However, its roots are not Christian.  Also the carving of gourds goes back to Europe.  Pumpkins were just prevalent in US.

Comment: @stib - Search highlights might be showing a regional holiday image, but it's show different images in the past, which are more generic.  The holiday aspect of your question is entirely not important. Search Highlights I might add is not a new feature. There is a good chance it was enabled if you happened to have installed the entitlement package for Windows 10 22H2 a few days ago.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound the term "Search Highlights" is what I needed

Comment: Disable by right clicking the windows toolbar, choosing "Search" and "disable Search Highlights".